# Finding number of total games for a badminton game with a concept of 'inheritance' when winning

Tags: logic, solution-verification

> In a badminton singles tournament, each player played against all the others
> exactly once and each game had a winner. After all the games, each player
> listed the names of all the players she defeated as well as the names of all the
> players defeated by the players defeated by her. For instance, if A defeats B
> and B defeats C, then in the list of A both B and C are included. Prove that
> at least one player listed the names of all other players.
>
> [Source: ISI UGB 2013](https://www.isical.ac.in/%7Edeanweb/dean_bstat_bmath_2013.pdf)

I found a way to find a player who has name of all other players, I just wish to check if my proof is logically sound.

Suppose we have $N$ players, then to start, choose any two players and consider their winner, now consider a game of this winner with another player, now consider winner of this game with another player.... keep doing this till you exhaust through all the players, the last player would have name of all other players due to the fact that in each game, they inherited the names of the players defeated and all those defeated by those players defeated.

Comment: As the question is exactly stated, I would say the logic is not completely convincing. The question implies there is a 'depth' of 2 to the inheritance. For example, P1 loses to P2, P3 loses to P2, P2 loses to P4, and P4 loses to P5. What does P5's list look like so far? According to the question, it would be $(P4,P2)$, not $(P1,P2,P3,P4)$

Comment: Hmm I can't imagine showing it without assuming infinite inheritance depth

Comment: It is indeed true, but it's a bit tricky to see. An inductive argument is the right approach; it might be helpful to think in terms of directed graphs

Comment: This test is definitely testing intuition one has for higher math topics... which I seem to have a low amount of. I'll check out the directed graph thing you mentioned.

Comment: I'm sure that's not true! It's tricky. I certainly don't think I would have been able to do this in high school. If you want help coming up with the solution I am happy to provide it, I just thought you might prefer to try on your own first